# discover interface classes at runtime

Tags: java, interface, discovery

I have a base interface `FunctionCredential`:

```
public interface FunctionPrivilege {}
```

and several other interfaces extending this interface:

```
public interface ReadSomethingPrivilege extends FunctionPrivilege {}
public interface WriteSomethingPrivilege extends FunctionPrivilege {}
...
```

The interfaces are used as **marker interfaces** only (no implementations). I want to discover interfaces (all reachable using the current context classloader), not check known interfaces.

Within a Java application, can I somehow discover (list) those interface classes at runtime? If so, how would I do that?

Note: CDI does something similar, also discovering/scanning classes at runtime.

Comment: I think you can do something with reflection

Comment: You want to get `ReadSomethingPrivilege` and `WriteSomethingPrivilege` from `FunctionPrivilege` ?

Comment: What are you expecting, to list all interfaces that extends `FunctionPrivilege` ? Or to know if an Interface extend it. If you want to list this, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/520339/4391450) could interest you

Comment: If I could just list all classes, I'd be happy, as I can check the classes myself using reflection (check if interface and if it extends the base interface).

Comment: Probably you can use Guava's [ClassPath](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html).

Comment: Classindex may help: https://github.com/atteo/classindex

Comment: _"I want to discover interfaces (all reachable using the current context classloader)"_ - beats me what that means.